# smach error message

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

smach.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Attempting to access the currently opened container, but no container is opened.

what does this mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245426/smach-error-message/) by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you provide the code leading to this error?

Anyways, it sound like you are calling `smach.StateMachine.add(...)` outside of a `with my_statemachine:` environment.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1